# Use Tab Key to fire same .hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keypress

I would like to fire the same .hover function (as seen below) when you press the Tab button on the keyboard.

```
$('.staffContainer .item').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).find('.staff-layer').fadeIn("fast");
                    $(this).find('.work-description').fadeIn("fast");
                    $(this).find('img').addClass('transition');
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).find('.staff-layer').fadeOut("fast");
                    $(this).find('.work-description').fadeOut("fast");
                    $(this).find('img').removeClass('transition');
                }
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> button doesn't generate a `hover` event, it generates `focus` and `blur` events. To achieve the functionality that you're looking for, you can do something like this:

```
function active() {
    $(this).find('.staff-layer, .work-description').fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).find('img').addClass('transition');
}
function inactive() {
    $(this).find('.staff-layer, .work-description').fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).find('img').removeClass('transition');
}
$('.staffContainer .item').hover(active, inactive).focus(active).blur(inactive);
```

Comment: I understand a tab button doesn't generate a hover. I just would like the same effect to happen when a user presses the Tab key. Which I know = 9 I think. Sorry, I'm very new to Javascript and jquery and I'm learning how to convert non Accessible sites to be Accessible.

Comment: @JesseBrewer Yes, the `Tab` has the key code `9` but it is kind of difficult to do this using the `keypress`events. As I've mentioned in my answer, you can use the `focus` and `blur` events. My example doesn't trigger a hover when an element is focused but it executes the same function (`active`) which should have the same effect.

Comment: @JBrew30 Great. I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'blur' event:

```
$('.staffContainer .item').bind('blur',
            function() {
                $(this).find('.staff-layer').fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).find('.work-description').fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).find('img').addClass('transition');
            },
            function() {
                $(this).find('.staff-layer').fadeOut("fast");
                $(this).find('.work-description').fadeOut("fast");
                $(this).find('img').removeClass('transition');
            }
        );
    });
```